# CalendarView into android fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, calendarview

Is there anyway I can retrive the date from a `CalendarView` and use just the date information(not the visual part) in another `Activity` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `getDate()` method. Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html#getDate%28%29) for the API documentation. Then, you can pass this to another `Activity` using `Intent`.

**EDIT**

You can do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Date date = null;
    CalendarView v = new CalendarView( this );
    v.setOnDateChangeListener( new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            date = new Date(year, month, dayOfMonth);
        }
    });
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("long date", date.getTime());       
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! and how can I use it to store in a database?

Comment: Refer this - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: Please mark as correct if you found the answer helpful. For any further queries, you can post another question or edit accoringly :)

Comment: new question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485072/get-extras-from-intent-as-long] @AndyFaizan